# Setting layers for a Dynamic Bayesian Network with bnstruct in R

Tags: r, dynamic, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I am currently creating a DBN using bnstruct package in R. I have 9 variables in each 6 time steps. I have biotic and abiotic variables. I want to prevent the biotic variables to be parents of the abiotic variables.For a Bayesian Network, it's pretty easy to implement using for instance `layering = c(1,1,2,2,2)` in `learn.dynamic.network()`.

But a problem rises for the Dynamic part: I would like to keep preventing biotic variables to be parents of abiotic ones in every time step while preventing edges to appear between any variables from t+1 to t.

If I use in `layering =`:

- 1 for abiotic variables at t1
- 2 for biotic variables at t1
- 3 for abiotic variables at t2
- 4 for biotic variables at t2...

I allow biotic variables from t-1 to explain the abiotic variables at t (and I don't want that).

So I tried:

```r
## 9 variables for 6 time steps 
test1 <- BNDataset(data = timedData,
                   discreteness = rep('d', 54),
                   variables = colnames(timedData),
                   node.sizes = rep(c(3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3), 6)
                   # num.time.steps = 6
                   )


## the 5 first variables are abiotic, the 4 last are biotics
dbn <- learn.dynamic.network(test1, 
                             num.time.steps = 6, 
                             layering = rep(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),6))
```

So now, I don't have any edges from biotic to abiotic (that's nice), but I have edges from variable_t(n+1) to variable_t(n).

I know that in `bnlearn` you can create a "blacklist" of edges that you don't want to see but I don't see any equivalent arguments in bnstruct. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `mmhc` algorithm that is used as default, you can use the `layer.struct` parameter to specify which pairs of layers are allowed to have edges between them. `layer.struct` takes a binary matrix where cell `i,j` is `1` if there can be edges going from variables in layer `i` to variables in layer `j`, and `0` otherwise.

The best way to use this is to combine it with the manually-specified layering of your first solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect, the combination of both arguments `layering =` and `layer.struct =` does what I wanted.

I post what I used here just to provide an example:

```r
## DBN study
dbn <- learn.dynamic.network(test1, 
                             num.time.steps = 6, 
                             layering = rep(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,  # set 2 layers per time step
                                              3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,
                                              5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,
                                              7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,
                                              9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,
                                              11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12)),
                             layer.struct = matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  ## allow certain layers to connect to others by hand
                                                     1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
                                                     1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
                                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
                                                     1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),c(12,12)))
```

Thanks for the quick answer and the package btw